# After upgrading to 12.10, Empathy displays 'network error' when connecting to Google Talk

Tags: networking, 12.10, empathy, connection, google-talk

After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, Empathy displays 'network error' when trying to connect to Google Talk. In 12.04 (and earlier versions), Empathy was setup and functioning correctly using Google Talk.

In Online Accounts, I have my Google account authorised with Ubuntu. I have tried removing the account and re-adding/re-authorising, but the result is the same.

I have also tried removing and re-installing Empathy (3.6.0.3) and Telepathy.

Is there a solution to this problem? Or a way to diagnose the 'network error' further? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empathy includes a debugger which can be used to display logging information to help diagnose connection issues.

Launch the debugger using: `empathy-debugger`, then start empathy and logging information will immediately be visible.

In this case, the logs showed the following:

```
    gabble/-WARNING: 22/11/12 22:44:08.389273: Invalid numeric port '80"
                                               specified in hostname
                                               talkx.l.google.com:80
```

This is an error caused by a misconfiguration of the fallback servers in `/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service`. A patch is available in the related [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1081839).

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be because of a corporate firewall interfering with the connection.
I got around the issue with the following parameters in the "Advanced" section.

```
Login ID: username@gmail.com
Password: **
[x] Encryption required (TLS/SSL) (checked)
[ ] Ignore SSL certificate errors (unchecked)
Resource:
Priority: 0
Server: talk.google.com
Port: 80
[ ] Use old SSL (unchecked)
```